# c# overwrite current line in a Rich Text box (return cursor to left of line before writing)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Windows app that I am trying to write the current downloaded amount of a file to a richtextbox.
I'm trying to get this is to output on the same line, overwriting the pervious details, however, I am only managing to get to append the pervious data.

> 0.01 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.01 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.08 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.08 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.14 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.14 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.18 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.24 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.24 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.27 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.33 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.33 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.34 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.39 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.45 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.45 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.52 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.52 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.58 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.58 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.65 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.65 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.71 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.71 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.73 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.79 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.85 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.90 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.93 MB's / 7.53 MB's0.99 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.00 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.06 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.06 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.12 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.13 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.19 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.19 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.25 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.26 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.32 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.32 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.38 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.39 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.44 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.50 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.50 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.50 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.57 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.57 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.63 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.63 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.69 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.70 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.75 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.81 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.81 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.81 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.87 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.87 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.94 MB's / 7.53 MB's1.94 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.00 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.00 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.06 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.06 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.12 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.12 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.18 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.19 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.25 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.25 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.31 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.32 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.37 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.43 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.43 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.43 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.50 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.50 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.56 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.56 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.62 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.64 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.70 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.71 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.77 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.77 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.84 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.85 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.91 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.92 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.98 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.98 MB's / 7.53 MB's2.99 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.05 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.06 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.12 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.12 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.12 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.18 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.19 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.19 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.25 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.25 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.30 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.37 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.37 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.43 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.43 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.49 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.50 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.56 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.56 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.62 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.62 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.63 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.69 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.69 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.69 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.74 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.80 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.80 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.87 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.87 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.93 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.93 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.99 MB's / 7.53 MB's3.99 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.05 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.11 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.11 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.18 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.18 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.24 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.24 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.31 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.31 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.36 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.42 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.43 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.49 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.49 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.56 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.56 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.62 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.62 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.67 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.74 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.74 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.80 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.80 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.87 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.87 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.93 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.93 MB's / 7.53 MB's4.99 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.05 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.05 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.11 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.11 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.18 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.18 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.24 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.24 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.30 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.31 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.37 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.37 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.42 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.48 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.49 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.55 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.55 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.61 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.61 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.66 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.68 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.74 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.80 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.86 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.92 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.92 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.99 MB's / 7.53 MB's5.99 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.04 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.11 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.11 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.17 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.17 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.23 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.24 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.30 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.30 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.36 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.42 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.42 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.48 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.49 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.55 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.55 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.62 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.62 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.67 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.73 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.73 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.80 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.80 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.86 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.86 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.92 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.93 MB's / 7.53 MB's6.98 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.04 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.04 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.11 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.11 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.17 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.17 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.23 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.24 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.29 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.29 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.35 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.36 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.42 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.42 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.49 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.49 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.53 MB's / 7.53 MB's7.53 MB's / 7.53 MB's
>
> Download completed!

What i'm trying (badly) to do is get

> 7.53 MB's / 7.53 MB's
>
> Download completed!

where the "7.53 MB's / 7.53 MB's" line changes, from "0.01 MB's / 7.53 MB's" at the beginning all the way though to the "7.53 MB's / 7.53 MB's" (or, how ever big the file is).

the code I have tried is

```
            int firstCharIndex = richTextBox1.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();


        // Calculate download speed and output it .
        if (richTextBox1.SelectionLength == 0)
        {
            int lineNumber = richTextBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(firstCharIndex);
            richTextBox1.Focus();
            richTextBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's\n",
    (e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),
    (e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00")));
            firstCharIndex = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
        }
```

I hope I have made this clear (Basically, I would like to overwrite the current line with download data, until the download is completed).

Can someone help me out  ?

thanks

Comment: What UI framework are you trying to use? (WPF, UWP, WinForms, etc.)

Comment: Hi, Its WPF. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

remove Append method:

```
richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Clear();
richTextBox1.Document.Blocks.Add(
                             new Paragraph(
                                 new Run(
                                     string.Format("{0} MB's / {1} MB's\n",(e.BytesReceived / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00"),(e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024d / 1024d).ToString("0.00")
                                 )
                             );
```

update: [image: no erros]

Comment: Hi #Rovann, I tried this before posting, and get "non-invocable member "richTextBox1.Text" cannot be used like a method.

Comment: new error message:  'RichTextBox' does not contain a definition for 'Document' and no extension method 'Document' accepting a first argument of type 'RichTextBox' could be found

Comment: Are you sure you're using wpf?

Comment: I think so. Solution properties say it's a .Net Framework 4.6.1 Windows application , and I have things like  private System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox richTextBox1;

Comment: You are using windows forms (`System.Windows.Forms.RichTextBox`). This control should work with .Text but if your project is really wpf, remove the reference to windows forms.